# Why isn't my imperial to metric calculation function working?

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a webpage based scientific calculator, where it have some basic functions i.e. +,-,*,/. but I wanted to add Cm to Inch and Inch to Cm conversion in it too, and that's where I am having issues it is not performing these two functions only other than this all functions are working.

```js
var display = document.getElementById("screen");
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
  
Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, function(button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (
    button.textContent != "=" && 
    button.textContent != "C" && 
    button.textContent != "x" && 
    button.textContent != "÷" &&
    button.textContent != "in"&&
    button.textContent != "Cm") {
      display.value += button.textContent;
    } else if (button.textContent === "=") {
      equals();
    } else if (button.textContent === "C") {
      clear();
    } else if (button.textContent === "x") {
      multiply();
    } else if (button.textContent === "÷") {
      divide();
    } else if (button.textContent === "in") {
      LengthConverter_in();
    } else if (button.textContent === "Cm") {
      LengthConverter_Cm(valNum);
    }
  });
});

function equals() {
    display.value = eval(display.value)
    //checkLength()
    //syntaxError()
}

function clear() {
  display.value = "";
}

function backspace() {
  display.value = display.value.substring(0, display.value.length - 1);
}

function multiply() {
  display.value += "*";
}
function LengthConverter_in() {
    display.value = value/0.39370;
  }
function LengthConverter_Cm() {
  display.value = value*0.39370;
}
```

```html
<input id="screen"/>
<br/>
<button class="button">=</button>
<button class="button">C</button>
<button class="button">x</button>
<button class="button">÷</button>
<br/>
<button class="button">in</button>
<button class="button">Cm</button>
<br/>
<button class="button">1</button>
<button class="button">2</button>
<button class="button">3</button>
<br/>
<button class="button">4</button>
<button class="button">5</button>
<button class="button">6</button>
<br/>
<button class="button">7</button>
<button class="button">8</button>
<button class="button">9</button>
<br/>
<button class="button">0</button>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: I would imagine they're both erroring out, if they are getting called, beacuse `value` isn't defined anywhere, but you're trying to use it in both of those functions.

Comment: @Cineris this is the answer. `value` needs to be changed to `display.value` in both length converter functions. Oh, and `LengthConverter_Cm(valNum)` needs to remove the `valNum`.

Comment: It's a little odd to bind the same generic handler to *all* buttons and then do a big series of if/else branches to figure out which button was clicked. Instead you would typically bind specific handlers to buttons that contain the specific functionality for that button. You also probably want to do something like add a data attribute to your button, to decouple its functionality from whatever text appears on the button. Imagine, for example, that you replace your textual buttons with images, or decide to change `in` ro `inches`. Your functionality should be decoupled from such changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the two functions value is not defined, but you are using it. it needs to be changed to display.value

```
function LengthConverter_in() {
    display.value = display.value/0.39370;
}
function LengthConverter_Cm() {
  display.value = display.value*0.39370;
}
```